# nHibernate big queries timeout

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, timeoutexception

We are developing a new system for a customer and we have a member table with about 23600 members. And when we are trying to get them all it times out. I have used sql profiler to get the question and run it separatly and it took about 3 secs.

```
using (ISession s = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
   return CreateCriteria(typeof(Member)).List<Member>();                    
}
```

It looks like the problem is that the mapping of the result of 23600 objects takes too long.
When limiting the results to for an example 300 (.SetMaxResults(300)) it works fine. I dont know right now if we ever would need to actually get all members in the final system, but i know when the time comes we would like to get most members to generate the their accounts in the membership provider of our site.

Member mapping (fluent nHibernate):

```
        Id(x => x.ID).Default("NEWID()");
        Map(x => x.LegacyID).ReadOnly();
        Map(x => x.Username).Length(32);
        Map(x => x.Password).Length(32);
        Map(x => x.MemberID).Length(10);

        Map(x => x.FirstName).Length(50);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Length(50);
        Map(x => x.Gender).CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.BirthDate);
        Component(c => c.Home);
        Map(x => x.Email).Length(80);
        Map(x => x.SendInformation).CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.SendInvoice).CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.Comment);
        Map(x => x.PublicProfile);
        Map(x => x.EntryDate);
        Map(x => x.ResignationDate);

        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.MemberStatus, "StatusID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.MemberType, "TypeID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.NationalAssociation);
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.Position, "PositionID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.SpecialSkills, "SpecialSkillsID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.CompanyType, "CompanyTypeID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.JobType, "JobTypeID");
        References<ProfileItem>(x => x.GraduateCity, "GraduateCityID");
        HasManyToMany<ProfileItem>(x => x.Interessts).Table("MemberInterests")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserID").ChildKeyColumn("ProfileItemID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();
        HasManyToMany<ProfileItem>(x => x.Properties).Table("MemberProperties")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserID").ChildKeyColumn("ProfileItemID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Not.LazyLoad();

        Component(c => c.Company).ColumnPrefix("Work");
        Component(c => c.Invoice).ColumnPrefix("Invoice");

        Map(x => x.Created);
        Map(x => x.CreatedBy).Length(32);
        Map(x => x.LatestChange);
        Map(x => x.LatestChangeBy).Length(32);

        Map(x => x.ElementarySchool);
        Map(x => x.University);
        Map(x => x.GraduateYear);

        Map(x => x.Title).Length(50);

        Map(x => x.LibraryAccess);
```

Anyone know anything about this problem or how to fix it ?

Comment: does the time increase linear (setmaxresults 100, 200, 300)? IMO in open bounded collections one should always process batches(pagination).

Comment: also if you just want to grab these members to import elsewhere then consider using a stateless session

Answer (score 1):

Fetching so big dataset is not a good idea. Think about memory consumption. If you need process this data, consider processing in **batches** (up to 1000 items). If you need present data to user, consider **paging**. If cannot reduce fetched dataset, you can increase timeout, but it is not recommended practice.